# how to add id attribute to radial-gauge in reactjs (or how to set 100% width and height to gauges)

Tags: reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas

I am using canvas-gauges in Reactjs. When I try to render direct canvas it's not rendering the canvas, so I have used `<RadialGauge units='km/h'>` react components. Here, I am not able to set 100% height and width for gauges. I don't want to set as it as `px`. Installed the following package by `npm install react-canvas-gauges`

```
<RadialGauge
  id='mycanvas'
  units='rpm'
  title='x1000 RPM'
  width={200}>
</RadialGauge>
```

Actual working code with `px` value

```
<Row>
   <Col md="12" xl="12">
   <Card>
      <CardBody className="dashboard-card-widgets" >
         <Row>
            <Col md="6" xl="6">
            <RadialGauge
            units='rpm'
            title='x1000 RPM'
            width={200}
            height={200}
            value={3}
            minValue={0}
            maxValue={8}
            majorTicks={['0', '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']}
            minorTicks={5}
            borders={false}
            strokeTicks={true}
            highlights={[{from: "6", to: "8", color: "rgba(200, 50, 50, .75)"}]}
            ColorPlate={'#fff'}
            borderShadowWidth={0}
            needleType={'arrow'}
            needleWidth={3}
            needleCircleSize={7}
            needleCircleOuter={true}
            needleCircleInner={false}
            animationDuration={1500}
            animationRule={'linear'}
            fontNumbersSize={30}
            ></RadialGauge>
            </Col>
         </Row>
      </CardBody>
   </Card>
   </Col>
</Row>
```

Expected result in render:

```
<canvas id="mycanvs" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
```

Comment: <canvas id='mycanvas' width="100%" height="100%" />  this what i want to get it on render

Comment: or is there any way i can use (https://canvas-gauges.com/documentation/examples/ ) this gauges directly in reactjs ?